# Trouble with Deployment of a Rails App to Heroku

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

More specifically, I am getting an H10 error when pulling up heroku logs, “No such file to load — pry (LoadError)” when running the rails console on Heroku.

The Rails app runs fine on `localhost`.  I've scoured all of my application's files to remove references to "require 'pry'", and any calls to "binding.pry".  The `pry-rails` and `pry-nav` gems should not be running in production on Heroku.  I've rerun `bundle install`, reset my databases both locally and on Heroku, ensured my code was pushed up after these adjustments, and have reset the dynos on Heroku.

What gives?

**heroku logs**

```
2016-05-02T21:45:04.892586+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=chess-workout-andrew-smith.herokuapp.com request_id=f05db461-e4ef-48e4-b920-6b5163fa0ea2 fwd="69.156.77.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2016-05-02T21:45:05.175027+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=chess-workout-andrew-smith.herokuapp.com request_id=fdbd387c-63fa-49e7-8d2c-e94f36558356 fwd="69.156.77.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

**heroku run rails c**

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': No such file to load -- pry (LoadError)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': No such file to load -- pry (LoadError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /app/app/controllers/pieces_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_or_load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:289:in `depend_on'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:207:in `require_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:61:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'simple_form'

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

gem 'pg'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem 'pry-rails', :group => :development

gem 'pry-nav', :group => :development

gem 'awesome_print', :group => :development

group :development, :test do
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4.1'

gem 'sprockets', '<= 2.11.0'

gem "devise"

gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
```

**database.yml**

```
development:  
  adapter: postgresql  
  encoding: unicode  
  database: chess_workout_development  
  pool: 5  
  username: postgres  
  password: password  
  host: localhost  


test:  
  adapter: postgresql  
  encoding: unicode  
  database: chess_workout_test  
  pool: 5  
  username: postgres  
  password: password  
  host: localhost  

production:  
  adapter: postgresql  
  encoding: unicode  
  database: chess_workout_production  
  pool: 5  
  username: postgres  
  password: password  
  host: localhost
```

Comment: There might be more information in the remainder of the error backtrace. Also the first version of rails 4.0.x compatible with ruby 2.2.0 was quite a few versions later

Comment: @FrederickCheung
I've included the detailed error backtrace above, but nothing meaningful is sticking out when I look at it.  You think that using Rails 4.0.1 with Ruby 2.2.0 could be causing the problem when deploying to Heroku?

Comment: It's definitely what causes the circular argument references. Looks like you might have a reference to pry in pieces_controller.rb (line 1)

Comment: @FrederickCheung Upgrading to Rails 4.0.9 solved the problem.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error log from `heroku run rails console` said that there is no `pry`. In `Gemfile`, pry was only for develop environment even though I am pretty sure that require 'pry' was set in controller file so that heroku is confused.

You can remove pry from `:group => :development` in Gemfile, and do not forget to `heroku run bundle install`.